# What are the real problems with the support of the site/portal in languages from right-to-left (using the React.js)?

Tags: reactjs, right-to-left

everyone! I would be grateful to everyone who can share the experience in developing/supporting sites/portals in languages from right-to-left (such as Arabic, etc.) using the React.js framework. What could be the problem?

Comment: The first one coming into my mind is the margin or padding of your content, but not really related to react, but rather a HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: @AntonieFrau, thank you very much for any feedback) but we can use PostCss-rtl, right?